# Using python with ml

Tags: machine-learning

I have not GPU support so it often happens that my model takes hours to train. Can I train my model in batches , for example if I want to have 100 epochs for my model,but due to power cut my training stops(at 50th epoch) but when I retrain my model I want to train it from where it was left (from 50th epoch).

It would be much appreciated if anyone can explain it by some example. https://timbu.com user

Comment: Maybe it can be helpful to tell us which framework you are using for ML

Comment: If you use scikit-learn, some models (for example MLPClassifier) have a warm_start parameter that allow to retrain them using the previously fitted parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The weights are already updated, retraining the model with the updated weights without reintializing them will carry where it left.

You can work with online notebooks like google's colab or microsoft azure notebook if you have ressources problems. They offer a good working environnement, colab for exemple has gpu and tpu enabled and 16go ram limit.